# VBoxManage: error: Cannot read the partition information from '/dev/disk0'

Tags: command-line, virtualbox, partitioning, osx-lion

I'm trying to make a partition `.vmdk` file for Virtual Box. Basically I want to boot my bootcamp partition box up in Virtual Box. But I get the following error when I try to make the `.vmdk` file

```
VBoxManage: error: Cannot read the partition information from '/dev/disk0'
VBoxManage: error: The raw disk vmdk file was not created
```

Here's the exact sequence of commands I typed in terminal

```
sudo chmod 0777 /dev/disk0

sudo chmod 0777 /dev/disk0s4

sudo VBoxManage internalcommands createrawvmdk -filename WinXP.vmdk -rawdisk /dev/disk0 -partitions 4

VBoxManage: error: Cannot read the partition information from '/dev/disk0'
VBoxManage: error: The raw disk vmdk file was not created
```

Comment: Were you ever able to figure this out? I'm encountering this issue as well and not finding any solutions.

Comment: @CAOakley I'm afraid I never did. I actually don't even have a Mac anymore. If you do figure it out, please post an answer :)